# How to intercept $resource requests

Tags: angularjs

Would there be a way to intercept requests in the $resource call?

I want to add an OAUTHv2 header to it, instead of specifying this for every resource model.

Currently I'm only able to intercept the *response*, as stated in the docs:

> ...
>
> interceptor - {Object=} - The interceptor object has two optional
>   methods - response and responseError. Both response and responseError
>   interceptors get called with http response object. See $http
>   interceptors.

I know you can push a global interceptor on $http, but I don't want to include my Bearer token in any request outside API calls (security...)

Anybody who is doing OAUTHv2 must have come across this problem. A pity there is no standard way in Angular.JS...

Answer (score 4):

Though, it's not obvious, there is a way to intercept $resource request.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Intercept resource request</title>
  <style type="text/css">.ng-cloak { display: none; }</style>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]).
      factory(
        "services",
        ["$resource", function ($resource)
        {
          return $resource(
            "http://md5.jsontest.com/",
            {},
            {
              MD5: 
              {
                method: "GET",
                params: { text: null },
                then: function(resolve)
                {
                  this.params.text = "***" + this.params.text + "***";
                  this.then = null;
                  resolve(this);
                }
              }
            });
        }]).
      controller(
        "Test",
        ["services", function (services)
        {
          this.value = "Sample text";

          this.call = function()
          {
            this.result = services.MD5({ text: this.value });
          }
        }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Test as test">
  <label>Text: <input type="text" ng-model="test.value" /></label>
  <input type="button" value="call" ng-click="test.call()"/>
  <div ng-bind="test.result.md5"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### How it works:

1. $resource merges action definition, request params and data to build a config parameter for an $http request.
2. A config parameter passed into an $http request is treated as a promise like object, so it may contain then function to initialize config.
3. Action's then function may transform request as it wishes.

The demo can be found at [transform-request.html](http://rawgit.com/nesterovsky-bros/angularjs-api/master/angularjs/transform-request.html)

[Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562141/831007) I've already shown a similar approach used to cancel $resource request.

See also: [Intercept angularjs resource request](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2015/05/07/InterceptAngularjsResourceRequest.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) interceptors

You can pass them in options for `$resource` methods

Article on that: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Comment: Yeah I know you can push interceptors globally on the $http object. What I want is to only intercept API calls. I've edited my original question.

Comment: You can intercept based on any condition of the `$http` config, so you could easily use a check like `config.url.indexOf('/api') === 0`

Comment: @Pepster there is an example with Session request interceptor in the article I gave you link to. Just add condition for URI

Comment: Thanks, I have asked the question about global interceptor before. I'm looking for the scoped approach as I don't want to do a string compare each time.