# Angularjs aborted promises still delay other promises

Tags: angularjs

I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440177/angularjs-how-to-cancel-resource-promise-when-switching-routes) and figured out the direct solution (that being, I was able to cancel a promise/request when the route changed). However, I'm encountering another, related problem that I think belongs in a separate question so here it goes:

I'm able to abort my promise when the route changes just fine (as you can see from the question I linked). However, for some strange reason, any other requests on the other route are delayed when resolving. See my dev tools screenshot below.

Here's the scenario: I load route A, which makes the call to `/api/categories` and you can see it takes 30ms which is normal. Then I navigate to route B, then before it's done loading I return to route A. When I return, the call to `/api/categorySites/1` is cancelled, and you can see when that happens as the gray bar ends. This is done by aborting the promise. However, back on route A again, the call to `/api/categories` doesn't resolve until that gray dot appears again on the request that was cancelled. That second call to `/api/categories` shouldn't take 2.23s, it should be closer to 30ms.

[image: Dev tools]

What's going on here? I would think the second Route A request would be just as fast as before. I need to get this to work faster. My code is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440177/angularjs-how-to-cancel-resource-promise-when-switching-routes). Let me know if you think I should include it again here. It's hard for me to imagine this isn't a common problem too...

Comment: Hmmm... did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same.

Comment: I couldn't find a way. You'd think this was a more-common issue. What I did instead was improve my back-end processing speed by using caching so that the script didn't take so long so it was less noticeable to the front-end user. Of course that's not ideal and didn't really solve the problem. If you find an answer, please let me know!

Comment: When you're trying to make a request #6 changing route doesn't cancel the request but cancels promise. After changing route you make request #7 which calls the server and I suppose it can serve only one request simultaneously so you see that gap. What's in the back end?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post but I did look into this and this sounds like eager vs. lazy asynch transition that I read about in Emberjs documentation recently. On your routes (and subsequent aborts) fulfills the promise (completes), moves along to your re-route request.

I believe this can be improved with a state controller.

[There is an Angularjs ui-router state controller that might be of use.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

[Here are example examples.](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/future/index.html)

[Angularjs routing documentation (for posterity).](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

So this is about `$routeProvider` (Angularjs default) enhanced by `$stateProvider` (ui-router) to expedite aborted routes.

Hope this is helpful (roughly 312 days later).