# Which is the "right" way to handle a response that came late

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Lets say that we have two buttons, each on are calling the following method:

```
var NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_REQUEST_RETRIES = 3;
var IMAGE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 3000;


processImage: function(image_data) {
    var main_response = $q.defer();
    var hash = getImageHash(image_data);

    var requestsCounter = -1;

    requestImage = function() {
      $http.post(apiUrl, {params: {data: hash},timeout: IMAGE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT})
       .then(function(response) {
           return main_response.resolve(response.data);
        }, function(error) {
        if (++requestsCounter < NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_REQUEST_RETRIES) {
          requestLabelsImage();
        } else {
          return main_response.reject();
        }
      });
    };

    requestLabelsImage();

    return main_response.promise;
}
```

The method passes an image related data to the server, the server process the data and then response. Every time a user press a different button different `image_data` is being send to the server.

**The problem:**

The user press button 1, the method is called with `image_data_1`, and then he/she immediately press button 2 and the method is called with `image_data_2`. The `processImage` function is called by another method, lets say `doSomethingWithTheResponse` which only cares about the latest user's action, but the `image_data_2` is proceed faster by the servers, so the client gets `image_data_2` before `image_data_1`, so the client believes that `image_data_1` was related to the user's latest action, which is not the case. **How can we ensure that the client is always getting the response that is related to the users latest action?**

Note: The hash is different for the differente `image_data` requests.

I was thinking something like:

```
var oldhash = null;

processImage: function(image_data) {
    var main_response = $q.defer();
    var hash = getImageHash(image_data);
    oldhash = hash;

    var requestsCounter = -1;

    requestImage = function(hash) {
     if(hash === oldhash){

      $http.post(apiUrl, {params: {data: hash},timeout: IMAGE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT})
       .then(function(response) {
           return main_response.resolve(response.data);
        }, function(error) {
        if (++requestsCounter < NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_REQUEST_RETRIES) {
          requestLabelsImage(hash);
        } else {
          return main_response.reject();
        }
      });

    }
    else {
      main_response.reject();
    }
   }

    requestLabelsImage(hash);

    return main_response.promise;
}
```

But I am not 100% sure that this is the right approach.

Comment: Can you not just cancel the first request when the second button is pressed? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29

Comment: "don't let your users be able to do things until they should". Why not just keep button 2 disabled until button 1's response came back and was processed?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans because from UI/UX requirements, the user should be able to click as many times and with any order the buttons (and send requests to the server) but the client should present the results for his latest action.

Comment: You could also filter somehow. `if (image_data_1) { /* do this */} if (image_data_2) { /* do that */}`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply disregard the previous requests.

You can create a repository of requests (array or dictionary implementation is okay). Call `.abort()` on the previous ones once another request is made -- when you add it in your storage.

If you want a dictionary, there is a good example [here](http://www.code-experience.com/async-requests-with-react-js-and-flux-revisited/) (tackles a different topic, though), but here is a modified snippet of his code which is related to your case:

```
var _pendingRequests = {};

function abortPendingRequests(key) {
    if (_pendingRequests[key]) {
        _pendingRequests[key].abort();
    }
}
```

*Where the `key` can be.. say... a category of your action. You can name constants for it, or it can be just the name of the button pressed. It can even be a URL of your request; completely up to you.*

There is an excellent explanation of the whole concept here:

> **jquery abort() ajax request before sending another**
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313022/594992

Comment: I implemented it using your idea thats why I upvoted it, having a repositoryOfRequests, with key the has and value the promise, canceling the promise every time a new request arrives. Thx ton.

Comment: I hope it worked out for you. Please do not forget to put a check mark on the correct answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If your UI allows for initiation multiple actions, while *processing* of those actions are mutually exclusive, then you should probably use promises, and track active promises.

```
button1.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  startRunning( task1.start() );
});

button2.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  startRunning( task2.start() );
});
```

With a task runner like:

```
function startRunning( promise ) {
  while(runningTasks.length>0) {
    cancel( runningTasks.unshift() );
  });
  runningTasks.push( promise );
}
```

Your `cancel` function can come from anything that can deal with promises, like Angular's `service.cancelRequest`, or you can write your own code that takes the promise and smartly breaks off its operation.

Of course, if you're not using promises, then you probably want to start doing so, but if you absolutely can't you can use a manager object like:

```
button1.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { task1(); });

button2.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { task2(); });
```

with

```
var manager = [];

function cancelAll() {
  while(manager.lenght>0) {
    var cancelfn = manager.unshift()
    cancelfn();
  }
  return true;
}

function task1() {
  var running = cancelAll();
  manager.push(function() { running = false; });
  asyncDo(something1, function(result) {
    if(!running) return;
    // do your real thing
  });
}

function task1() {
  var running = cancelAll();
  manager.push(function() { running = false; });
  asyncDo(something2, function(result) {
    if(!running) return;
    // do your real thing
  });
}
```

And you can put cancels on as many aspects as you need. If you need to cancel running XHRs, you might be able to do so, if you have multiple steps in your result handling, cut off at each step start, etc.

Comment: I upvoted your question even if it is not exactly what I need because I learned from it ;) Thx Mike

Comment: that's the best way to vote, points if it's useful, even if it's not the final answer, and a nice big checkmark for the "correct answer" =)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal use-case for promises. Basically, whenever a new request is made, you want to cancel any existing promises. I am not versed in AngularJS, but the following ng-specific links might prove useful:

> [Angularjs how to cancel resource promise when switching routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440177/angularjs-how-to-cancel-resource-promise-when-switching-routes)
>
> [Canceling A Promise In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2731-canceling-a-promise-in-angularjs.htm)