# How to kill $resource service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using $resource in my project.
Making POST request and calling api.
But after 30 seconds I want to kill the http request.
How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs how to cancel resource promise when switching routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440177/angularjs-how-to-cancel-resource-promise-when-switching-routes)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ngResource.$resource), you can specify a timeout parameter on the `$resource` actions. I'm assuming it would look something like this (since you specified a POST request I guess you must be calling `.$save` or `Resource.save`):

```
$resource('/foo/bar/:id',{id :'@id'},{
    save: {method: 'POST', timeout: 30000} // 30 seconds in milliseconds
});
```

Note that the `timeout` parameter can be:

> timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

Haven't tested this at all but hopefully it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the cancellable: true in the query object so that request can be cancelled at any point.

```
var request = $resource('/foo/bar/:id',{id :'@id'},{
query: {method: 'get', isArray: true, cancellable: true}});

var apiCall = request.query({location: destination});
apiCall.$cancelRequest();
```