# .resolve() cancel future requests not current in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need cancel the current pending ajax request, when I try use .resolve() method then all subsequent AJAX call are aborted, but not the current. I use angular AngularJS v1.4.5

Comment: [Check this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24456539/6229597) I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know and it's used as an argument for using the [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) that has support for cancelable observables.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479435/1594980) is also related.